# HowTo parse numbers from string with BOOST methods?

Tags: parsing, boost

**Problem**: Visual C++ 10 project (using MFC and Boost libraries). In one of my methods I'm reading simple *test.txt* file.

Here is what inside of the file (`std::string`):

```
12 asdf789, 54,19 1000 nsfewer:22!13
```

Then I need to convert all digits to *int* only with **boost** methods. For example, I have a list of different characters which I have to parse:

```
( ’ ' )
( [ ], ( ), { }, ⟨ ⟩ )
( : )
( , )
( ! )
( . )
( - )
( ? )
( ‘ ’, “ ”, « » )
( ; )
( / )
```

And after conversation I must have some kind of a massive of int's values, like this one:

```
12,789,54,19,1000,22,13
```

Maybe some one already did this job?

PS. I'm new for boost.

Thanks!

---

### Update

---

Here is my sample:

```
std::vector<int> v;

rule<> r = int_p[append(v)] >> *(',' >> int_p[append(v)]);

parse(data.c_str(), r, space_p);
```

All I have to do, is to add additional escape characters (`,'[](){}:!`...) in my code, but did not find how to do that!

Comment: @rmflow Is it possible not to use `boost::regex` and trying to use something like mentioned here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/ini_file_parser_spirit.aspx (Grammar definition section)?

Comment: @mosg : Not with Boost.Regex, but it is with (static) [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/xpressive/index.html) if you only need a lexer and not a parser.

Comment: @ildjarn, @Roel, @Nicol Bolas - I need a parser. Just for now I'm trying to update sample code above to read numbers from the "dirty" string... But no one doesn't gave me the correct answer... Different methods I could found by my self!

Comment: @mosg: If I knew what you meant by "*a list of different characters which I have to parse*" I would help, but as it is your question doesn't make much sense to me. What relation does that table of characters have to the pre- and post-conversion data?

Comment: @ildjarn Ok. I'd like, using `boost::spirit` syntax parse `12 asdf789, 54,19 1000 nsfewer:22!13` string to int vector, like `12,789,54,19,1000,22,13`. Also in code I need to use chars `,'[](){}:!` which I want to use as escape chars, like `','` from the sample above! Is that clear? Thnx!

Comment: @mosg : I'm not sure what you mean by "escape chars" in this context? Do you really mean "delimiters"? If so, the single character delimiters make sense, but how do double characters like `( ‘ ’ )` make sense as delimiters? I.e., can you give an example that contains `( ‘ ’ )` and show the output you expect?

Comment: @mosg : Yes, I read your question -- did you read mine? "*can you give an example that contains `( ‘ ’ )` and show the output you expect?*" Also, calling someone dumb who you expect to help you is pretty damn dumb.

Comment: Thanks, ildjarn, but I'll try to find an answer by myself. I gave  you all explanations which I could... Repeat 4 times - no, thanks - I'll faster read all boost::spirit official docs and post here correct answer! And by the way, sorry, for the word - I just tiered to search such a simple solution for so long time!

Comment: @mosg : You're repeating answers to _questions I didn't ask_. You have yet to give an example that contains `( ‘ ’ )`, which is the only thing being asked for. The irony of you calling someone else's reading comprehension into question here is palpable.

Comment: @ildjarn Ha! "-1" - and that is you answer?!) Great job kid...

Answer (score 0):

- Easy way out is regex.
- Hard way out is using spirit
- Middle-of-the-road is using algorithm::string::split, with the correct separators, and then looping over all individual parts using lexical_cast<>(). That way you can filter out the integers.

But again, regex will be much more robust plus it's much cleaner than all sorts of primitive string manipulation hacking.

Comment: @ildjarn: Clearly, you've never used Spirit. Regex is a simple pattern matching system. Spirit has concepts of parsing, attribute propogation, the skipper (to ignore non-digits), etc. Regex is very simple; Spirit is complex.

Comment: @Nicol : I use Spirit on a daily basis. Learning one DSL is no different than learning another; the fact that Spirit is an EDSL doesn't change that fact, especially considering that most of the functionality you just mentioned is completely optional for simple use-cases.

Comment: @Nicol: using Spirit can be difficult for non-trivial grammar, but it doesn't have to be for the simple things like this. You only need to learn the basic rules to create parser for this case. I actually liked Spirit, the only thing I didn't like was the long compilation times.

Comment: To any future readers who are not familiar with the above techniques, the above commenters are being purposefully obtuse, ignore them. For any realistic interpretation of 'difficult', spirit is a lot harder than getting a regex working for the purposed outlined here. Claiming that driving a space shuttle isn't harder than driving a bicycle because in the end they're just two vehicles to get you from point A to point B is just semantic weaseling, but at least in the space shuttle case every normal person would be able to call them out on it.

Comment: Oh and if somebody still disagrees, I challenge them to post sample implementations of the given problem in both spirit and regex, and we'll let others decide which one is the simplest.

Comment: @Roel : I'll take on that challenge, as soon as I figure out what the OP actually wants. ;-]

Comment: @Roel: the only reason I posted AXE example instead of Spirit is because for last two years I forgot the syntax, but it's pretty much a one-liner in Spirit, just like example in AXE.

Comment: @ ildjam, yes it seems like the OP isn't really interested in getting an answer, given the limited effort he seems to be willing to put into this. I'm already regretting answering this question. Anyway, thinking more of it, if all he wants to do is ignore all non-numeric characters he could use a skipper I guess, probably there is already one like it in spirit; which wouldn't need to be long in terms of code. I still think a regex is simpler in terms of time it would take to write, required background knowledge, future programmers reading his code etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to regex, boost::spirit, and manually parsing the text, you can use AXE parser generator with VC++ 2010. The AXE rule would look something like this (not tested):

```
std::vector<unsigned> v;
auto text_rule = *(*(axe::r_any() - axe::r_numstr()) & ~axe::r_numstr() 
   >> axe::e_push_back(v)) & axe::r_end();
// test it
std::string str("12 asdf789, 54,19 1000 nsfewer:22!13");
text_rule(str.begin(), str.end());
// print result
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](unsigned i) { std::cout << i << '\n'; });
```

The basic idea it to skip all input characters which don't match the number string rule (`r_numstr`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a **BOOST** example.

Comment: @mosg Seems like you're not looking for an example, but rather for somebody to do your job for you. How about you'd actually try to understand what people are telling you and making an effort at asking directed question, and/or answering the questions people ask you to clarify your problem statement?